# Flutter: TextField controller prevents content from being pushed up

Tags: flutter, user-interface, textfield

I just encountered this really strange phenomenon that I am putting a TextField at the bottom of my screen, everything is wrapped in a scaffold and when the textfield is clicked the whole content is being pushed up (note: I used a SingleChildScrollView for this).

But now using a controller to make use of all the functionalities of a textfield, this automatic pushing upwards suddenly vanished and I have no idea how to make it stay and work simultaneously to the textfieldcontroller. It seems like I have to choose between the two.

Does anyone has an idea why this happens and how to fix this?

Edit: Code example:

So, this code snippet would work like I intent: I click on the textfield and the whole content is pushed up.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 400,
            ),
            TextField()
          ]
        )
      )
    )
  }
```

This one does not, though. The keyboard covers the content. And I have no idea why that is the case.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var textFieldController = TextFieldController();

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 400,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: textFieldController,
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    )
  }
```

Comment: Please show the code as a text om code format to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Just edited the post, please have a look! :)